# Why am I seeing the following warning message from google cloud composer even when my variables have update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I am creating a composer environment and added two custom environmental variables `gcs_source_bucket` and `gcs_dest_bucket` and I get the following warning. I checked and the variables have been updated and I am a bit perplexed as to what the **warning** is all about.

```
Executing within the following kubectl namespace: composer-1-7-5-airflow-1-9-0-8de1cbf3
[2019-10-02 16:30:11,232] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-10-02 16:30:11,261] {configuration.py:389} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-10-02 16:30:11,281] {app.py:43} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
```

And these are the commands I am using:

```
gcloud composer environments run environment_name --location us-central1 variables -- --set gcp_project ksdsadsa-lb-sdsds

gcloud composer environments run environment_name --location us-central1 variables -- --set gcs_dest_bucket gs://sdsfsd3-c4309490-image-bucket-backup

gcloud composer environments run environment_name --location us-central1 variables -- --set gcs_source_bucket gs://skskdsj-catalog-image-bucket
```